# Native animated module is not available - react native

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I'm using `react native` for my project and strangely I'm getting **error** like shown in below image. I don't understand what's this error. Can someone help to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: The code would be really useful ;) How are we going to solve your problem otherwise?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8602 this might help you

Comment: Thanks for the link @Jeffrey, I already checked it

Comment: That would be a wonder if an issue from 2016 is still in the newest version of RN, but who knows ;) Since you didn't provide any information, I assume you are using at least RN v0.40...

Comment: Yes @Jan Peter, I'm using the latest version of RN

Answer (score 2):

Added RCTAnimation to podfile. It worked!

```
pod 'React', :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [

    'Core',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTImage',
    'DevSupport',
    'BatchedBridge',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
    ]
```